# Transclude does not work on select with ng-options

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-transclude

I've found [this](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-create-custom-select-boxes-using-css-and-jquery.php) cool article about designing custom select boxes.
I decided to wrap the jquery function in a directive:

```
angular.module('App')
  .directive('customSelect', function () {
    return {
      template: '<span class="select-wrapper">' +
          '<div ng-transclude></div>' +
          '</span>' +
        '<span class="holder"></span>',
      transclude: true,
      restrict: 'A',
      priority: 1000,
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
          //pass
      }
    };
  });
```

html:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 left">
    <select custom-select ng-options="productGroups.indexOf(product) + '' as product.name for product in productGroups" ng-model="userData.pg"></select>
</div>
```

but for some reasons it just doesn't do anything

found [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1099) github issue, that speaks about the same topic, but doesn't really address my issue here.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to have the select and the ng-options in the same element? I would guess that ng-options is set 'terminal: true' much like ng-repeat. Try nesting the options in a separate div.

I guess I'm saying that there's probably something in the ngOptions directive definition that are causing a problem with your custom select so either try to debug that in angular.js or write a custom options directive. If you passed an array to the compile function in your directive definition you could probably loop through the array duplicating within a piece of 'option' html. This is similar to how ngRepeat works.

Comment: So what you're saying basically is that I cannot use the ngOptions directive, and need to hack t he options repeating in a non-W3C-compliant way to make this work?

Comment: var ngOptionsDirective = valueFn({ terminal: true });
line 21475, angular.js 1.2.4